# None block 'while True' using asyncio

Tags: python, apache-kafka, python-asyncio, confluent-platform

Using below code I'm attempting to start 2 infinite loops using asyncio:

```
async def do_job_1():
    while True :
        print('do_job_1')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def do_job_2():
    while True :
        print('do_job_2')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(do_job_1())
    asyncio.run(do_job_2())
```

`do_job_1` blocks `do_job_2`, as `do_job_2` never prints do_job_1. What mistake have I made ?

Ultimately I'm trying to convert kafka consumer code:

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError

settings = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'client.id': 'client-1',
    'enable.auto.commit': True,
    'session.timeout.ms': 6000,
    'default.topic.config': {'auto.offset.reset': 'smallest'}
}

c = Consumer(settings)

c.subscribe(['mytopic'])

try:
    while True:
        msg = c.poll(0.1)
        if msg is None:
            continue
        elif not msg.error():
            print('Received message: {0}'.format(msg.value()))
        elif msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
            print('End of partition reached {0}/{1}'
                  .format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))
        else:
            print('Error occured: {0}'.format(msg.error().str()))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

finally:
    c.close()
```

taken from https://www.confluent.io/blog/introduction-to-apache-kafka-for-python-programmers to be concurrent so I can parallelize processing of Kafka messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `help(asyncio.run)`:

> It should be used as a main entry point for asyncio programs, and should ideally only be called once.

But you can use `asyncio.gather` to join the tasks:

```py
import asyncio

async def do_job_1():
    while True :
        print('do_job_1')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def do_job_2():
    while True :
        print('do_job_2')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(do_job_1(), do_job_2())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```